# JavaScript, Grunt files Create a task to include everything but the 'src/com' inside concat

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

It works but I don't understand what the hell I did, I need to know if the "js", "css" properties is what the task looks for???

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        js: {
            src: [
                'src/intro.js',
                'src/core/*.js',    
                'src/outro.js',
                'src/com/*.js'                  
            ],
            dest: 'builds/barefoot-js.full.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        js: {
            src: 'builds/barefoot-js.full.js',
            dest: 'builds/barefoot-js.min.js'
        },
    },
    cssmin: {
        minify: {
            src: 'css/barefoot-js.css',
            dest: 'builds/barefoot-js.min.css'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-aetheon-cssmin');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify', 'cssmin']);

}
```

It works but I don't understand what the hell I did, I need to know if the "js", "css" properties is what the task looks for???

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks

> When a task is run, Grunt looks for its configuration under a property
>   of the same name.

So for the *concat* task there is a corresponding *concat* part in the *grunt configuration* object.

That *concat* task specification is done in the subobject

```
js: {
        src: [
            'src/intro.js',
            'src/core/*.js',    
            'src/outro.js',
            'src/com/*.js'                  
        ],
        dest: 'builds/barefoot-js.full.js'
    }
```

It specifies what to do. So the *target* for this task is *js*.

The *uglify* task has a target *js* and the *cssmin* task has a target *minify*.